# How to fix [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'

Tags: java, eclipse, web, gwt

I want to start a Web Development project with GWT in Eclipse. For that I am following the tutorial on http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html

The form to create the Project does not exactly look like they explain. For example I cannot make a checkmark at "Use Google App Engine" since it does not exist. To get the build.xml I checkmarked the "Generate an Ant Project" field.

When I try to run the generated code, the following error occurs:

```
Turning off precompile in incremental mode.
Super Dev Mode starting up
workDir: /tmp/gwt-codeserver-9585554490549923267.tmp
2019-02-03 18:36:10.619:INFO::main: Logging initialized @879ms
Loading Java files in com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.StockWatcher.
[ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'      either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
```

When I try to use the command line version of their tutorial, I get an 503 Error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /StockWatcher.html. Reason:

    Service Unavailable

Powered by Jetty://
```

I use GWT SDK 2.8.1 and Java 10

I installed already lots of plugins for Eclipse, so that I am quite sure to have all plugins I need. Maybe this could be something with the Java version? Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: The Eclipse plugin has been updated. Take a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x04sufQce-Y The "Use Google App Engine" has been removed (use Google Cloud Plugin instead). And, as the error message suggest: check, if you added the "com.google.gwt.user.User" module inside the moduel descriptor.

Comment: If you just want a minimal starting-guide with gwt, I have created this tutorial which is updated to last best-practices (https://dev.to/ibaca/modern-gwt-first-steps-509k) but it is for client only app (minimal example!). Otherwise, I recommend using the tbroyer archetype (https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes).

Comment: Make sure you name your gwt tests like `GwtTest___` to avoid them being picked up by the surefire plugin. The gwt plugin will run them in a separate test step (if you use GwtTestSuites).

Answer (score 9):

1. Check that your gwt.xml really inherits "com.google.gwt.user.User"
2. Check java sdk. Some gwt versions work only with java 1.8
3. If you use Idea, there was a bug, which also causes this error: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218731?_ga=2.120118728.1133270638.1599566675-1712334692.1566210515

Answer (score 6):

Use 1.8.0 JRE to compile the GWT application.
You can setup this in eclipse as shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJDPh.png)

Then try to compile the application you will get the following output in console.

Compiling module com.somshine.miniproject.MiniProject
Compiling 5 permutations
Compiling permutation 0...
Compiling permutation 1...
Compiling permutation 2...
Compiling permutation 3...
Compiling permutation 4...
Compile of permutations succeeded
Compilation succeeded -- 21.193s
Linking into D:\Java\gwtProject\miniProject\war\miniproject
Link succeeded
Linking succeeded -- 0.426s

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to a `JDK` 1.8 version folder, as `ant` will use that to compile your sources

Answer (score 1):

On Eclipse when you get this error, you should navigate to `Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs` and make sure that whichever item is selected, is actually a JDK.

If it's not, change it to your JDK and make sure it's working with Java 1.8 SDK.