# Not able to create module in GWT in eclipse

Tags: gwt

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MjQg9Mssqw&t=183s) link to write my first gwt hello world program in eclipse. I created GWT Project in eclipse,then I want to create module for that,then I right clicked on package,new-->module
in gwt,then it is not going to next step, that is the problem..

Comment: Could you provide some details? Screenshots?

Comment: here I created gwt new project, then i created package also in eclipse, then i want to create gwt module, in the eclipse wizard i selected module(gwt),then i clicked on next, it's not going to next step,it is staying in the same page only,not going forward.

Comment: @DeviGeorge I suggest that you take a more modern approach when working with gwt, the tutorial you posted is very old, you can always create a new project and then import it to eclipse or what ever IDE you use, recently there was this nice quick start guide for GWT https://dev.to/ibaca/modern-gwt-first-steps-509k which not only will help you create a new GWT project but will also will make you understand how gwt works, and if still want updated eclipse tutorials please check this channel https://www.youtube.com/user/branflake2267/search?query=gwt

Answer (score 1):

1- Start eclipse

2- From eclipse marketplace seearch for `gwt`

3- install `Eclipse GWT plugin 3.0.0`

4- From eclipse menu select window -> preferences

5- open entry `GWT -> GWT settings`

6- Click `Download` button, this will take you the gwt sdk download page.

7- Donwolad and extract the latest sdk.

8- From eclipse `GWT setttings` preference window click on `add`

9- Select the extracted SDK folder.

10- Check the check box next to the new added SDK to make it default.

11- click `Apply and close`

#### Create and run a project

1- Locate the gwt plugin action button in the toolbar.

2- Select the button and select `New GWT application project ...` from the dropdown.

3- Enter the project name and package then click `Finish`

4- Select the newly created project and from the GWT action button select `GWT compile project`.

5- Once the compilation is completed, Right click the project then select Run as -> 2 GWT Development mode with jetty.

6- Once ready double click the url of the HTML to open it in the browser.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, while following the above steps,in first part, step-9, here gwt-user.jar is missing, like that one error message is coming,so not able to add latest sdk to eclipse, i checked some websites for solution,but can't help.please suggest.

Comment: You are not pointing the right directory, point to the directory where you extracted the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

@Devi George: As in your case the suggested above by @Ahmad Bawanesh answer didn't help resolving the caption issue. There is nothing in the answer that actually mentions "module", let alone how to add one. I've had everything set up as explained, and still had a compiler error. What helped to address it described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67316333). Next, you should make sure the Java JRE setting in Eclipse preferences points to the installed JRE 1.8 location and is selected as the default. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505911) got it covered.

As to the actual question on adding a module to a GWT project, you can always add a file and name it as needed with an [xml file extension](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html). Search the page for "Modules: Units of configuration" on how to configure the newly created xml file. Obviously, it must have a module tag inside, among other things.