# GWT error even on official tutorials: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly

Tags: gwt

I am learning GWT and was trying to run [this tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GWT/article.html) by Vogella and also the [official GWT tutorial](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/index.html).

Using the Eclipse GWT plugin 3.0 on Windows 10 and JDK 11

I marked the `Maven Project` checkbox.

When I right-click and Run As

```
Turning off precompile in incremental mode.
Super Dev Mode starting up
   workDir: C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-8137229043727681777.tmp
2021-04-29 12:03:13.494:INFO::main: Logging initialized @718ms
   Loading Java files in de.vogella.gwt.helloworld.De_vogella_gwt_helloworld.
   [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
```

I see that it is inheriting User

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.8.1//EN"
  "http://www.gwtproject.org/doctype/2.8.1/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='de_vogella_gwt_helloworld'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='de.vogella.gwt.helloworld.client.De_vogella_gwt_helloworld'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505911/how-to-fix-error-hint-check-that-your-module-inherits-com-google-gwt-core-co) was not relevant to my issue.

Comment: You don't have a link to the tutorial you mentioned

Comment: There are great tools to start: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes, https://github.com/NaluKit/gwt-maven-springboot-archetype, https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-cli and http://www.mvp4g.org/boot-starter-nalu/BootStarterNalu.html for example. Another great place to get informations is: https://github.com/lofidewanto/awesome

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly you are either missing gwt-user.jar from your classpath, or somehow the gwt-user.jar version doesn't match the gwt-dev.jar, which will cause problems. Every module automatically inherits com.google.gwt.core.Core (despite the error message), and as your .gwt.xml shows, you already have User added.

--

Additionally, from your linked SO post, do check the comments - there are some better, more modern tutorials listed.

Comment: In the java build path I see the GWT SDK with both those jars. Will the jars on the classpath be different? I was also trying to follow the 2017 tutorial in LinkedIn Learning by Kyle Wintner. Same error.